# Chat with an expert feature!

Tags: discussion

I like the new feature "Chat with an expert" it is a very good replacement for the real users on this web site. I assume it is farmed out to Indian call center that answers some very useful problems.

So, how do we assign reputation to these hard working individuals?

[image]

Comment: Check the date on calender :p

Comment: Easter Monday, the resurrection of Jesus, yes, I see you point

Comment: @Doogfar: That was Sunday.

Comment: Question on the Mecca of Stack Exchange: [What is “chat with an expert”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)

Comment: I think someone has a case of the "Mondays."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robots are not interested in reputation. So don't worry about it

Comment: Data from Star Trek might disagree with that

Comment: @Doogfar Although inspired by Isaac Asimov's robot stories, Lieutenant Commander Data self-identifies as an android and not as a robot. :)

Answer (score 4):

I actually thought it was some kind of virus. The expert kept telling me to find an expert. So I told her she was the expert and she said I should call an expert. I told her I would call her if she called me back first. Said bye and left.

She never called me back. :(

Comment: Oh, I would run Norton Virus checker in Wine imediatly if I was you

Answer (score 2):

For someone who was in "Office Space," she really isn't very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Today would be the first day of the ancient Jewish calender.  If Jews or others celebrated new years day to day (in the passed) they could have been called a fool by their roman peers.(which would have been the least of their worries)  Which is why 1st of April is April fools day!?
Hope nobody posts my conversation with Ask an Expert!